# PPTPD VPN only forward DNS requests?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, vpn, bandwidth

Is there any possible way of configuring a PPTPD VPN server to only forward DNS requests on so that I can save bandwidth?

Thanks, Francis

Comment: Doesn't that defeat entirely the point of using a VPN?

Comment: I would like the VPN so that users would be forced to use specific DNS servers but I don't have the bandwidth to allow all of their traffic to travel through my VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with the PPTP server-- this is all a function of the client.

You could use the built-in IP routing functionality in your clients to handle this. Assign the clients DNS servers that are only accessible via your VPN in RFC 1918 address space. When the client connects to the VPN its routing table will be populated with a route to the PPTP network and the DNS servers will be accessible.

What type of clients you have will determine how easy this is to accomplish. You'll also want to figure out what the behavior of the clients should be when the PPTP VPN is down. You'll also have to deal with the chicken-and-egg problem that the clients won't be able to use DNS to locate the PPTP server since the clients won't have DNS service until the VPN is up.